# HTML/Javascript Set up Two Select Options and redirect once first one is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<select id="First DropDown" name="" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
   <option value="/url">Option1</option>
   <option value="/url">Option2</option>
   <option value="/url">Option3</option>
   <option value="/url>Option4</option>
   <option value="" selected="selected">Option5</option>'
</select>
 <select id="Second DropDown" name="" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
       <option value="/url">Option1</option>
       <option value="/url">Option2</option>
       <option value="/url">Option3</option>
       <option value="/url>Option4</option>
       <option value="" selected="selected">Option5</option>'
    </select>
```

That's really all I got. Basically what I want is when someone selects an option (such as option 1) on the first dropdown menu, it then pulls up a specific set of options. So for example, if someone selects "Option 1" on the first drop down menu, then on the second drop down menu options such as "#1" "#2" "3" come up, but if someone selections "Option 2" on the first drop down menu, menu options such as "4" "5" "6" come up. I would also like to know how to set up a search button so that when both the drop downs have a specific set of option selected, it then redirects to a specific page I set. Sorry about all of this.. I know Im not very good

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event handler on the first text box that fills the second text box with options. A good way to do this is to store your options in a 2D array, so when the first select box is selected, your Javascript code can easily loop over and create the new options.

With HTML like this

```
<!-- In your own code, do not use onsubmit="return false" -->
<form id="searchForm" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="Search a little"/>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Search parameters</label>
        <select id="first" name="first"></select>
         <select id="second" name="second">
             <option>-----</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and Javascript like this:

```
var options = [
    ["A","B","C"],
    ["D","E","F"],
    ["G","H","I"],
    ["J","K","L"]
],
first = document.getElementById('first'),
second = document.getElementById('second'),
searchForm = document.getElementById('searchForm'),
searchButton = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]'),
destination,
option;

// Fill the second text box with options from the array.
function fillSecond() {
    // Get the list of options
    var secondOptions = options[first.value];
    // Clear the previous options
    second.innerHTML = '';
    // Add each option to the select box    
    for (var i = 0; i < options[first.value].length; i++) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = secondOptions[i];
        option.innerHTML = 'Option ' + secondOptions[i];
        second.appendChild(option);
    }
    // Select the first option by default.
    second.firstElementChild.setAttribute('selected','selected');

    // update the from 
    updateFormAction();
};

function updateFormAction() {
    searchForm.action = destination = '#' + first.value + second.value;
}

// When the second box is updated, update the second select
// and update the form action
first.addEventListener('change', fillSecond);

// Fill the first select box with options
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i;
    option.innerHTML = 'Option ' + i;

    first.appendChild(option);
}
// By default select the first element.
first.firstElementChild.setAttribute('selected','selected');

// When search is clicked, alert where the form will take them
searchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('Sending user to location: ' + destination);
    return false;
});

// When the second box is updated, update the form action
second.addEventListener('change', function () {
    updateFormAction();
});

// On startup, fill the second box.
fillSecond();
```

You can change where your form goes to based on which options the user selects from the drop down.

[See the demo at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BY6ha/) to get yourself started

Comment: I would've rather used an object to hold it, but I guess both do the job. Nice piece of code. Just wondering, why are you wrapping `updateFormAction()` in an anonymous function in the `addEventListener`  to `second`? I know it's useful to pass parameters, but what purpose here?

Comment: You can use an object as well with some tweaks! I call `updateFormAction` from both event handlers. This prevents my code from becoming "copypasta": I want to do the same thing in two places (in this case, update the form action), so I make a function for it instead of copy-pasting.

Comment: Not sure  you understood what I mean, so I'll clarify: why `second.addEventListener('change', function () {
    updateFormAction();
}, false);` instead of `second.addEventListener('change', updateFormAction, false)`? (btw the `false` is often explicitly stated for legacy browser support)

Comment: I see what you mean now, and that is probably more efficient. I am just used to writing anonymous function event handlers I guess : P

Comment: @cvializ I know that this is going to sound extremely newbie. But how Can I change the text for the two drop downs? I want it to be completely different text rather than a value that changes. In addition, how can I set it so that when it clicks submit, it goes to a different url for each set of selection?

Comment: You'll find it just by looking at the code, & you can tweak the fiddle to suit your needs. If you don't understand the code, that means you'll  have to learn some basic JS.

Comment: @Tyblitz, I have been trying to mess around with it for a while, the only thing I can't figure out is how to change The Option 0, 1, 2, 3 to different text.

Comment: THis line in the `for` loop : `option.innerHTML = 'Option ' + secondOptions[i];`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "Chained Select Box" - you can change the options values easy with Jquery, but better you take one Plugin which provides this functionality:

For Example:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html

Or here if you are using a Database (MySQL) and PHP to provide the Content of your Select Boxes

http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/